# Efficient way to check where the bullet came from player [Unity Multiplayer Mirror]

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-mirror

I'm new to mirror so bare with me. What I'm trying to do is when a player gets hit by the bullet of another player it can check whose bullet came from my option is:

```
1.) add player tag to bullet
```

or there is a better way using mirror

Comment: I don't know if this is a proper way but i think you can send the player's network id with the bullet so when the player got hit it can check whose id is it.

Comment: Tags are very limited and additionally you have to already define these tags beforehand! As already mentioned in the comment before: Tell the bullet the NetworkIdentity of the responsible player -> unique and scalable

Answer (score 1):

1. Attach **[Network Identity](https://mirror-networking.com/docs/Articles/Components/NetworkIdentity.html)** to root of bullet to ensure it spawns on other clients.
2. Create a **[NetworkBehaviuor](https://mirror-networking.com/docs/api/Mirror.NetworkBehaviour.html)** script to manage any logic or data associated with the bullet.
3. Add a single `int firingPlayerId;` field with the **[[SyncVar]](https://mirror-networking.com/docs/api/Mirror.SyncVarAttribute.html)** attribute to the script.
4. Update this variable whenever a player uses this object as a bullet to shoot (assuming you have some kind of caching going on, you'd need to change this).

Since NetworkIdentity makes sure variables are only synced when they are modified/dirtied, this won't cost you anything.